# SparkR: custom aggregete function

Tags: r, sparkr

I need to calculate aggregate using a native R function IQR.

```
df1 <- SparkR::createDataFrame(iris)
df2 <- SparkR::agg(SparkR::groupBy(df1, "Species"), 
  IQR_Sepal_Length=IQR(df1$Sepal_Length, na.rm = TRUE)
)
```

returns

> Error in as.numeric(x): cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [`gapply`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/reference/gapply.html), [`dapply`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/reference/dapply.html), [`gapplyCollect`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/reference/gapplyCollect.html) is created for! Essentially you can use a user defined function in Spark, which will not run as optimally as native Spark functions, but at least you will get what you want.

I would suggest you to start using `gapplyCollect` initially, then move on to `gapply`.

```
df1 <- SparkR::createDataFrame(iris)
# gapplyCollect does not require you to specify output schema
# but, it will collect all the distributed workload back to driver node
# hence, it is not efficient if you expect huge sized output
df2 <- SparkR::gapplyCollect(
  df1, 
  c("Species"), 
  function(key, x){
    df_agg <- data.frame(
      Species = key[[1]], 
      IQR_Sepal_Length = IQR(x$Sepal_Length, na.rm = TRUE)
    )
  }
)
# This is how you do the same thing using gapply - specify schema
df3 <- SparkR::gapply(
  df1, 
  c("Species"), 
  function(key, x){
    df_agg <- data.frame(
      Species = key[[1]], 
      IQR_Sepal_Length = IQR(x$Sepal_Length, na.rm = TRUE)
    )
  },
  schema = "Species STRING, IQR_Sepal_Length DOUBLE"
)
SparkR::head(df3)
```